# How can i connect this hello-flask-app with my database and create model in the database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I got this error trying to create a model for my database using fask_sqlalchemy

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3250,
> in _wrap_pool_connect
> return fn()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in
> connect
> return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in
> _checkout
> fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in
> checkout
> rec = pool.*do_get()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in
> *do_get
> with util.safe_reraise():   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line
> 70, in **exit**
> compat.raise*(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207,
> in raise*
> raise exception   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in
> _do_get
> return self._create_connection()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in
> _create_connection
> return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in
> **init**
> self.__connect()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 665, in
> **connect
> with util.safe_reraise():   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line
> 70, in **exit**
> compat.raise*(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207,
> in raise*
> raise exception   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in
> __connect
> self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 590, in connect
> return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line
> 597, in connect
> return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/home/mikado/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
> line 122, in connect
> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

My Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://mikado:@127.0.0.1:5432/hellodb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    
db.create_all()

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, you haven’t supplied any credentials for SQL:

`no password supplied`

You’ll need to use connection strings to pass the password as well as explained on https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config.html. Amending your existing connection string, replace the `<password here>` section with the relevant information:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://mikado:<password here>@127.0.0.1:5432/hellodb
```

Comment: My database doesn't have password

Comment: It worked altered the password of the user and then included it in the URI